# search should start only after entering 3 characters in any field

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, hibernate, jsp

I am using Spring MVC,hibernate and JSP in my application. 
Currently I have implemented functionality of search for multiple fields and I have called it on onKeyUp() function using JavaScript.
But now I want it to perform search only if there are atleast 3 characters in any field.
for example if there are 3 fields then if i enter 1 or 2 characters in one/two field and 3 characters in third field then it should call search method only on basis on 3rd field and it should ignore the input from other fields.
What will be the easy way to achieve this?

Comment: If you're already using jquery, why not use its existing autocomplete, which has a parameter for this? Otherwise, it seems clear how--don't make the request until the field is 3+ chars, and only send that field (or ignore the others).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to only execute the search functionality if one of multiple fields contain 3 or more characters.

Based off of solely that assumption and no other details something along the following should work:

```
$('.fields').each(function(k, v){
    var obj = $(this);

    obj.keyup(function(){
        if(obj.val().length >= 3){
            // Execute submission
            alert(obj.val());
        }
    });
});
```

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/FtE9H/

The above code assumes that you have assigned a class of `fields` to the desired fields that should be checked to execute the search functionality.  This could be modified to only look at specific element types but that is up to your full implementation.

In addition, you could empty the other fields on a successful match for a value with a length of 3 or more characters to avoid any possible confusion with your end users.